# Upgrade Error: ERROR: Could not connect to database specified in connectionString for SqlDataProvider In dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to install dot net nuke in my local system (windows XP). I have IIS and sql server 2005 express.

I have followed the instruction and all are done. While running the dotnetnuke i.e. http://localhost/DotNetNuke500-1/install/install.aspx I got the following error message

> Upgrade Error: ERROR: Could not connect to database specified in connectionString for SqlDataProvider

I don't know what is the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the database in the connectionString doesn't exist, or you have a permissions problem.  Be sure that the DB exists and that the Application Pool user has db_owner rights to the database.